# scan files and folders not in the htdocs directory - xampp and php

Tags: php, xampp

my currency htdocs directory is on c/xampp/htdocs/ 
i am trying to scan a folder on D:// drive to get a list of the files in it. 
i did it on the htdocs folder and it's working. but i can't do it in any other directory outside the htdocs.

Comment: I think By Default Apache server set a permission to public access to htdocs folder only.

Comment: it has to be away to extend the htdocs direcotry to another directory...

Comment: you can do it in apache's config file httpd.conf by changing the document root.

Comment: Is D a local drive or a network drive?  scandir() was able to retrieve a list of files from the root of my C drive (where xampp is located) as well as a mapped usb key, but not a network drive.